# How to trace the child windows opened in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have three links in my page, i want to restrict the user to open a link one at a time. So how to check through  javascript when user clicks on a link whether it has been opened already a window or not(by opened i mean not just click the link and close it, the window should be opened at the time when user clicks on link).

Comment: There's nothing you can do to prevent people from opening your links in windows. You can affect things by using window names and "target" attributes, but ultimately users have complete control.

Comment: This sounds cheesy. Forcing the user into doing exactly what YOU want is in most cases a bad idea.

Comment: show example of how the link looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the windows a name, then you can access them using the DOM. Every time a user opens a new popup window you could run a loop that will try and access all the popups. If another window is open already you can stop the current popup event from happening.

The popups would all have to be under your domain for this to work.

Comment: thanks for answering matt..i think giving same name for the windows would solve my problem..

Comment: I would give them all the same name but numbered e.g. popWin1, popWin2, popWin3, etc. Would be easy to traverse in a loop and you could distinguish which page is open in another window.